# jQuery.ajax int is being sent but $_POST returns NULL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When sending data to an ajax post call I get "NULL" returned.
I am sending a lot more data (which all works), but left it out of the snippet to make it more clear.

When I log the var in my console, it shows up. When I check the network tab if the data is properly sent, it shows up. When I var_dump the $_POST in PHP it returns NULL.

Jquery

```
function get_cars_ajax() {
    var filterAdvertentienummer = 119005595; // is number

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      'action' : 'get_cars_filter',
      'filterAdvertentienummer ' : filterAdvertentienummer,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data != '') {
        // DO SOMETHING
      } else {
        // DO NOTHING
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
}
```

PHP

```
function get_cars_filter() {
    global $post;

    $context = Timber::get_context();

    var_dump($_POST['filterAdvertentienummer']); // = NULL
    echo $_POST['filterAdvertentienummer']; // = empty string

    if (isset($_POST['filterAdvertentienummer'])) {
        $advertentienummer = $_POST['filterAdvertentienummer'];
    } else {
        $advertentienummer = "";
    }

    $queryList = '?skip='.$current_page.'&limit='.$limit.'&sort='.$sort.'&order='.$order;
    
    if ($advertentienummer != "") {
        $queryList = $queryList . "&advertentienummer=" . $advertentienummer;
    } else {
        var_dump($advertentienummer);
    }

    $args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'accept' => 'application/json'
        )
    );

    $results =  wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('http://IP/cars'.$queryList, $args));

    return $results;
}
```

[image: network tab clearly showing it does pass the data]

[image: var_dump and echo show empty var]

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the `NULL`? I don't see anything in your AJAX code where you actually log or show the data which was returned by AJAX, so I can't work out how you are determining that it's null. If you're seeing that `NULL` as a result of a _different_ HTTP request (e.g. the one where your page is first loaded, or something like that), then that's not at all surprising because POST variables only exist in the request where they were actually sent. If you look in your browser's Network tool at the AJAX request, you can see in the Response tab what PHP actually returns from that one

Comment: "When I var_dump the $_POST in PHP it returns NULL." Where does it return NULL? Here? `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` In the `ajax` `success` method?

Comment: When I sent the data it is filled - when I get the data in PHP it is NULL
What I do afterwards with the data after succes or error does not matter since it is not even in the PHP so I can't send anything back.

so Here:

```var_dump($_POST['filterAdvertentienummer']); // = NULL```

 ```echo $_POST['filterAdvertentienummer']; // = empty string```

Comment: `when I get the data in PHP`...again, how do you know? You didn't say _where_ or _when_ you're seeing that output from PHP, which is what we asked you.

Comment: `What I do afterwards with the data after succes or error does not matter since it is not even in the PHP`...you seem to have misunderstood how AJAX works, then. When you send an AJAX request, the data is sent (asynchronously, in the background) to the PHP script mentioned in the "url" option. Any output from that PHP script (e.g. from an `echo` or `var_dump` statement) is sent back as the response to the AJAX request. Because it's an AJAX request from Javascript, that response is given back to you in the `success` variable in your JS code. It does not show directly on screen or anything...

Comment: ...it's then up to you to write some Javascript code to deal with that response and process or show it however you want to. That is the whole point of AJAX - you can do something in the background without directly having to reload or change anything in the main browser screen, unless you specifically write JS code to do that. You won't see the response from PHP anywhere unless you either a) look for it in your browser's developer tools, or b) write some JavaScript to make it show on the screen somewhere.

Comment: So I can only assume that what you're seeing currently is actually the result of running a totally different HTTP request (not the AJAX request) - as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @ADyson ah sorry - you are correct, I misunderstood.
The data NULL comes from the succes data 

I will edit the code above a bit to show what I do with the data and how I return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a mistake in your ajax code.

**Your code line**:

```
'filterAdvertentienummer ' : filterAdvertentienummer,
```

you have added one **space** in the variable name so it's not gonna be readable by PHP.

**Modified code** :

```
'filterAdvertentienummer' : filterAdvertentienummer
```

Now PHP will read this variable as a string. You can convert strings in int with PHP.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO THANK MATE

Comment: If it's just a basic unintended typo like this, the question can just be closed. Typos are one of the listed reasons a question can be deemed [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it's unlikely to have much value to others trying to learn from it (other than as a lesson to always double-check and thoroughly debug their work)